# Error While Trying To Push Data To A Web Server In Flutter

Tags: php, flutter, dart

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
    FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br /> ^
    
    #0 _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
    #1 _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
    #2 _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
    #3 _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
    #4 JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
    #5JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
    #6 jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:155:10)
    #7 _LoginState.createAdminAccount (package:hibmat_desktop/screens/login/login_screen.dart:280:19)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

please i need some help. this is my async function for the post
request

```
     Future createAdminAccount() async {
        String url = "https://hibmat-software.000webhostapp.com/Models/Admin.php";
        var data = {
          "createAccount": action.toString(),
          "name": name.toString(),
          "email": email.toString(),
          "telephone": telephone.toString(),
          "pwd": pwd.toString(),
          "office": office.toString()
        };
        http.Response response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(url),
          body: data,
        );
        var results = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        if (results == "Account exists") {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Account already exist", gravity: ToastGravity.TOP_RIGHT);
        } else {
          if (results == 'insert') {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(content: Text('Account created'), width: 100.0));
            // Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/dashboard");
            print("inserted into DB");
          } else {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Didn't insert data");
          }
        }   }
```

Comment: Hello, can you please edit the code part so its easier to read? You can use the code section function in stackoverflow for it.

Comment: Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `body: data` to `body: json.encode(data)`, so that your data encoded to json format

Comment: just tried it didn't worked seemed there's some kind of convert error..

Comment: same error as last time.[ ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at line 2, character 1

Comment: _Why_ should OP try that? What would that fix? Please always add a little explanation

Comment: What am saying is am trying to push some data from my flutter App to a remote web server and the following error:

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: have already shared my async function above.. please i need some help

Comment: @NamkatCedrick Sorry for late reply, do you have access to the API? Try to print the request body so we know if the data being sent or not, and try to print `data` in flutter to make sure the data has value on it, because from what I know  `Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast` usually means you send null value  instead of string

Comment: yeah that's true... i am trying to signup a user from my flutter App to a php script on a web server but the return value using json_encode("data"), when i print this data on the flutter side it shows "data <br />" and the following error 

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 11)
"arrived;"\n<br />

Comment: Okay, after trying your code, it looks like the problem is your API, it returns null value when I try it.